# can I localize my iOS app to Spanish or German while keeping the rest of the phone in English?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

users want to keep our iOS app language setting totally separate from the user's iPhone language.  Basically, inside the app itself, the user selects the App's language, and then the app's UI and text all changes to the selected language.  This is more flexible than Apple's localization standards, and they don't address this situation. Is there some agreed upon best practice as to how to do accomplish this?

Specifically, a user might want the app's interface in Spanish, but the rest of the phone remains in English.

Thank you!

Comment: In Product|Scheme you can modify the existing scheme or create a copy.  In the "Run/Options" page, you can specify the "Application Language" and "Application Region" which can be used to launch the App with specific settings without the need to modify the device settings

Comment: thank you, but would a user be able to access this setting via the UI? I'm looking for "in-app language selection".  The default way "correct" way is for the app to follow the phone's language.

Comment: I'm not aware of away to do it in app, but that doesn't mean it can't be done

Answer (score 0):

Create the Localizable.strings as you do the default localization in iOS. Then use this code to achieve language switch with in the app.

```
extension String {

    func localized() -> String {

       let selectedLanguage = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey:) CURRENT_LANGUAGE) 

            guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: selectedLanguage == "en" ? "Base" : selectedLanguage, ofType: "lproj") else {

                if let basePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Base", ofType: "lproj"){

                    return Bundle(path: basePath)?.localizedString(forKey: self, value: "", table: nil) ?? self
                }

                return self
            }

            return Bundle(path: path)?.localizedString(forKey: self, value: "", table: nil) ?? self


    }
}
```

You can access the localized string by calling let `text = "LOGIN_SCREEN_TITLE".localized()` where ***LOGIN_SCREEN_TITLE*** is added in the localisation file.

```
enum LanguagesSupported: String {

    case English = "en"
    case French  = "fr"
}

UserDefaults.standard.set(LanguagesSupported.French.rawValue, forKey: CURRENT_LANGUAGE)
```

Comment: Do not use `value(forKey:)` to get data from `UserDefaults`. Use `string(forKey:)` in this case.

Comment: Oh yes thanks  @rmaddy.  Using it we can remove the casting right?

Comment: Yes, no cast is required with `string(forKey:)`. `value(forKey:)` is only to be used when you need key-value coding. You also need to remove the use of `synchronize()`. It is not needed and it is actually marked as obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

First create a dictionary of language code and language names like this

```
let applicationLanguages = ["de":"German","es":"Spanish"]
```

then when user can select particular language then after clicking on any button call this function and kill the app.

```
func setLanguage(languageCode: String){
        let languageArray = NSArray(objects: languageCode)
        UserDefaults.standard.set(languageArray, forKey: "AppleLanguages")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "changedLanguage")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(languageCode, forKey: "AppLanguage")

    }
```

Then show alert of selected language, then on the click of ok kill the app.

```
 func endBackgroundTask() {
     exit(0)
  }
```

Comment: This answer is dangerous and will likely get your app rejected (Section 2.1) > https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/