# iOS Localization using Xib & Swift: Can someone help me to make an multilingual app using XIB (not Storyboard) and Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, localization, internationalization, xib

I searched for tutorials for localization but all are for storyboard, my app is made up in xib. I also want to make the language change option inside my app using buttons, instead of changing it from Settings.

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/51605633/6818278 for implementing localization inside the app.

Answer (score 0):

You can use XMLParser for this feature.

- Place all your string inside an XML file and then read data from a
  file for the selected language.
- In delegate get a dictionary or key-value pair for string and then
  assign it to the label.

[image]

Ex:

```
    let xmlParser: XMLParser = XMLParser()
    xmlParser.delegate = self
    xmlParser.parseXml(withLanguageIndex: baseIndex)
```

// In delegate XMLParserDelegate

```
func getValues(_ valueDict: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    stringsXMLDict = valueDict
}
```

Hope it will help you. Happy Coddling:)